# How to change frequency of a millimeter wave?

Tags: frequency

I want to know, is there a surface or medium that can change or shift the frequency of a millimeter-wave?

I have seen some metamaterial elements that do it for THz and some optical methods, but I couldn't find anything about millimeter waves.

Comment: Millimeter wave mixers are common electronic products these days e.g. https://www.pasternack.com/pages/RF-Microwave-and-Millimeter-Wave-Products/millimeter-wave-waveguide-frequency-mixers.html

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of something that can reflect the signal with a modified frequency. It seems there are reflecting surfaces that can do it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the frequency of a wave is determined by its source. It can be Doppler shifted by reflection from a moving surface. Other than that you would need to absorb the energy and use that to generate a new wave.

Comment: The millimeter wave mixers in my comment above, when used as frequency converters, don't absorb the energy of the incoming wave.

Comment: @JohnDoty They have electronic components and significant conversion losses. Why is it known that they're not absorbing the energy of the incoming wave?

Comment: @BowlOfRed The way it works is that it rapidly switches the polarity of the signal. We don't normally think of a switch as absorbing and re-emitting the energy it's transmitting. But the frequency conversion produces both sum and difference frequencies. Usually, you throw away the energy at the frequency you don't want. The switches also aren't perfect. So, yes, there is some loss.